# how to add color to column values returned from resultset based on if-else condition in java

Tags: java, jsp

How I can add color to the text of column values which are returned from ResultSet in java.I have searched it and goggled it but of no use.The condition where I want to apply color on text is

> EDIT 1

```js
       public LinkedHashMap<String, String> beam_CurrentStatus() throws SQLException
{
 
 try

{
 con=getConnection();
 stmt = con.createStatement();
 
      String sql="SELECT TOP 1 c.logtime, a.BL1_data_SS_ST as BeamLine1,a.BL2_data_SS_ST as BeamLine2,a.BL3_data_SS_ST as BeamLine3,a.BL4_data_SS_ST as BeamLine4,a.BL5_data_SS_ST as BeamLine5,a.BL6_data_SS_ST as BeamLine6,a.BL7_data_SS_ST as BeamLine7,a.BL8_data_SS_ST as BeamLine8,a.BL9_data_SS_ST as BeamLine9,a.BL10_data_SS_ST as BeamLine10,a.BL11_data_SS_ST as BeamLine11, a.BL12_data_SS_ST as BeamLine12,a.BL13_data_SS_ST as BeamLine13,a.BL14_data_SS_ST as BeamLine14,a.BL15_data_SS_ST as BeamLine15,a.BL16_data_SS_ST as BeamLine16,a.BL17_data_SS_ST as BeamLine17,a.BL18_data_SS_ST as BeamLine18,a.BL19_data_SS_ST as BeamLine19,a.BL20_data_SS_ST as BeamLine20,a.BL21_data_SS_ST as BeamLine21,a.BL22_data_SS_ST as BeamLine22,a.BL23_data_SS_ST as BeamLine23,a.BL24_data_SS_ST as BeamLine24,a.BL25_data_SS_ST as BeamLine25,a.BL26_data_SS_ST as BeamLine26,a.BL27_data_SS_ST as BeamLine27,b.st1_prmt_status_p45,c.beam_current,c.beam_energy from INDUS2_BLFE.dbo.main_BLFE_status a inner join INDUS2_MSIS.dbo.main_MSIS_status b on a.logtime=b.logtime inner join INDUS2_BDS.dbo.DCCT c on b.logtime=c.logtime ORDER BY c.logtime DESC ";
    
    stmt.executeQuery(sql);
    rs = stmt.getResultSet();
    ResultSetMetaData rsmd = rs.getMetaData();
    while (rs.next()) 
    {
      if(rs.getInt(29)==1 && rs.getDouble(30)>110 && rs.getDouble(31)>2500)
     {
          for (int j = 2; j < 29; j++)
           {
          
             if (rs.getInt(j) == 1) 
             {
              // al.add(rs.getInt(j));
                count += 1;
                String name = rsmd.getColumnLabel(j);
              
                map.put(name, "Being Used");
                **//Here want to show Green color text** 
            
            }
             else
             {
              
              String name = rsmd.getColumnLabel(j);
             
              map.put(name, "Not Being Used"); 
              
             **//Here want to show Red color text**
             }
        }
      }
    }
}
 catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println("\nException in  Bean " + e.getMessage());
} finally {
    closeConnection(stmt, rs, con);
}
return map;
}
```

Right Now my output is coming as:-

> BeamLines     Status
>
> BeamLine1  OFF
>   BeamLine2    OFF
>   BeamLine3    OFF
>   BeamLine4    ON
>
> **Edit2**

My Edited jsp page is:

```js
  

 <head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
<style>
    .green {
        color: green;
    }

    .red    {
        color: red;
}
</style>
</head>
<table width="500px" border = "1" cellpadding="1"> 

    <tr> 
        <th>BeamLines</th> 
        <th>Status(1=Being Used)</th> 
    </tr> 

    <c:forEach var="country" items="${bs.beam_CurrentStatus()}">

        <c:choose>
            <c:when test="${country.value == 'OFF'}">
            <tr> 
                <td class="green"> ${country.key} </td> 
                <td class="green"> ${country.value} </td> 
            </tr> 
   </c:when>
      <c:otherwise>
            <tr> 
                <td class="red"> ${country.key} </td> 
                <td class="red"> ${country.value} </td> 
            </tr> 
  </c:otherwise> --> 
        </c:choose>

    </c:forEach> 

</table>
</body>
</html>
```

I want to show the **OFF STATUS with Red Color and ON with Green color.**
How to do that.I'm not using swing.
Thanks in advance.

After editing jsp ,No table content is being displayed i.e table is empty.Don't no where going wrong..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got this I guess... It's not that hard. :)

```
<style>
    .green {
        color: green;
    }

    .red    {
        color: red;
}
</style>




<table width="500px" border = "1" cellpadding="1"> 

    <tr> 
        <th>BeamLines</th> 
        <th>Status(1=Being Used)</th> 
    </tr> 

    <c:forEach var="country" items="${bs.beam_CurrentStatus()}">

        <c:choose>
            <c:when test="${country.value == 'OFF'}">
            <tr> 
                <td class="green"> ${country.key} </td> 
                <td class="green"> ${country.value} </td> 
            </tr> 

            </c:when>
            <c:otherwise>
            <tr> 
                <td class="red"> ${country.key} </td> 
                <td class="red"> ${country.value} </td> 
            </tr> 
            </c:otherwise>
        </c:choose>

    </c:forEach> 

</table>
```

dont forget to import the C: taglib by adding this above:

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
```

Please mark this as an answer if it helped you.

Comment: Multiple annotations found at this line:
 - Unknown tag 
  (c:otherwhise).
 - Unknown tag 
  (c:otherwhise).This exception is coming on <c:otherwise> when I do as You say.

Comment: Okay sorry, Was typing this out of my head. I had wrote otherwise wrong. it's otherwise without the H (instead of otherwHise)

Comment: Now nothing is being displayed in output,No table

Comment: Almost not posibble. check if the syntax is correct. And check if I'm using correct model value's. I'm not sure about that.

Comment: I have edited my jsp page ,as you said.Please see my question Edit 2 portion

Comment: Thanx a lot..its working now  **</c:otherwise> -->** this was giving error.:)

Comment: If you change ${country.value == 'OFF'} to ${country.value == 'ON'}, colors will be correct

Answer (score 0):

I see you are using JSP's? Color is a responsability for the View, and not for the Controller. You should add proper CSS properties on the 'titles' in your view.

Comment: yes I'm using jsp. My code for jsp is:**<table width="500px" border = "1" cellpadding="1">
 <tr>
 <th>BeamLines</th>
 <th>Status(1=Being Used)</th>
 
 </tr>
 <c:forEach var="country" items="${bs.beam_CurrentStatus()}">
   <tr>
   <td>  ${country.key}  </td>
   <td> ${country.value} </td> 

   </tr>  
</c:forEach>

</table>**

Comment: And what has to be in color?

Comment: I have to apply color based on if-else condition.How can I apply through jsp when my color is based on if -else condition.? I will apply greencolor to text when if condition satisfies else I will apply red color .

Comment: Have a look at JSTL, you can do such thing as <c:if test='x == y'><p class="green">myText</p> <c:else><p class="red">myText</p></c:if>

Comment: no color is being displayed as I'm not getting how to apply it.

Comment: give me the condition where you want to check on please.

Comment: You should provide more code. Give me the whole controller class please :). I can't link it to your mappings..

Comment: <c:forEach var="country" items="${bs.beam_CurrentStatus()}">
   <tr> 
   <td> ${country.key} </td> 
   <td> ${country.value} </td> 
  </tr> 
 </c:forEach>

How are they related to your controller? And on what condition does those lines have to appear in red or in green?

Comment: I have again edited my question and provided you with the code.When my inner if condition is true then I want the column name to be displayed in green otherwise in red color.